# What does the word "breakdown" mean here?

Tags: meaning

> CSS Support – A complete **breakdown** of the CSS support for every popular mobile, web and desktop email client on the planet.  <sup>Source: [GitHub](https://github.com/jonathandion/awesome-emails)</sup>

Couldn't find the right definition of breakdown on [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/). I suppose it's like a *complete guide*...

Comment: The definition [***1 e***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/breakdown) in Merriam -Webster is the one you are looking for: **division into categories :  classification; also :  an account analyzed into categories**.

Comment: Interesting and likely unintended second meaning, though.

Comment: There is not enough context to provide a definitive answer to the question and any answer is likely to be less-than-drfinative.  If CSS has had a complete breakdown, CSS has been rendered inoperative.  If an engine suffers a breakdown, it no longer works.  A complete breakdown of my taxes is likely to be a full description of how the tax liabilities occurred and how and when they are to be paid.  The quoted source is not even a complete sentence .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/breakdown) provides the relevant definition:

> 4. an analysis or classification of something into its component parts

Essentially, this means that it has a compositional analysis of CSS support for every popular mobile, web and desktop email client on the planet